# Python installing package through pip failed - Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: python, macos, package, pip, osx-yosemite

I can't install any package through python pip, it gives me the following message:

```
>pip install mathpy
Collecting mathpy
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement mathpy
  No distributions at all found for mathpy
```

The result of pip is the same for every package.
Pip searching just works:

```
>pip search mathpy
mathpy                    - Asks and checks math problems
```

My have the following setup:

```
Mac OS X 10.10.1 Yosemite
Python 2.7.9
pip 6.0.6
```

Please help.

Comment: `mathpy` seems to be an abandoned project. Why do you need it in the first place?

Comment: I need to install packages to get work with cv2 OpenCV library, also it seems that OpenCV can't be installed. How do you know if it is abandoned?

Comment: you cannot install opencv with pip https://jjyap.wordpress.com/2014/05/24/installing-opencv-2-4-9-on-mac-osx-with-python-support/

Comment: But that instructions doesn't work either because brew is always trying to download old version of OpenCV which is not available anymore

Comment: well, mac ports does its job :]